# How to exclude a word from regex subpattern?

Tags: regex, delphi

I am using Delphi 7 and TDIPerlRegEx. I am looking for verbs in parts of sentence which contain some specific part to identify the verb.

```
s1 := '(I|you|he|she|it|we|they|this|that|these|those)';
s2 := (can|should|would|could|must|want to|have to|had to|might);
RegEx_Seek_1.MatchPattern := '(*UCP)(?m) \b'+s1+'\b \b'+s2+'\b \K([^ß\W]\w{2,15})\b';
```

The key word which is wrongly included in result is "not"; but should be exluded:

Sample text:

... that you should **not** ßeat of every ...

Verb like this should be included in result:
Sample text:

lest he should **put** forth his hand ...

Now I would explain the part with ß sign. The ß sign says, that the original text had "not" word, and then the verb is followed. But I changed this text in previous interaction or session so the source text which I am working now is as stated above. The pattern `([^ß\W]\w{2,15})` should avoid the word which is used in negative sense. This is also why do not include the "negative" verb.

So point of the question is how to exclude the "not" word from the captured text; that is - captured by this pattern, which is either `([^ß\W]\w{2,15})` or `(\W{3,15})` .

I am using this pattern to replace substrings in text.

More sample text needed?

> than I can **bear**.  And
>
> so I might have **taken** her
>
> they might **dwell** together
>
> they could **not** ßdwell together
>
> lest you should **say**,

In group 3 I expect match:
for `bear`, `taken` (or posibly `have` instead of taken), `dwell` and `say`.
I am trying to exclude the `not` word, so any verb or word following `not` must be excluded from 3rd group or the match completely. I am interested about group 3 only. Group 1 and 2 just specifies alternatives preceding the verb.

Comment: There is not enough info here: 1) If you have `they could not ßdwell together`, should there be any match at all? 2) If yes, should Group 3 be "ßdwell"? 3) Should there be a match for `they could not dwell together`? If yes, what words should be in the groups?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew: I added info: In group 3 I expect match:
for `bear`, `taken` (or posibly `have` instead of taken), `dwell` and `say` ... I am trying to exclude the "not" from the group. That is `ßdwell` must not match in any case. Because it is negated by the `not` word.

Comment: So, `'(*UCP)\b'+s1+'\s+'+s2+'\s+\K(?!not\b)([^ß\W]\w{2,15})\b'` is not what you  are looking for, right? (Note you DO NOT need `(?m)` in this regex)

Comment: Try `'(*UCP)\b'+s1+'\s+'+s2+'\s+\K(?|(?=not\b)()|([^ß\W]\w{2,15})\b)'`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/d6YZYA/2)

Comment: My try with ?! https://regex101.com/r/d6YZYA/4

Comment: You know, it is hard to help you because you reject all the improvements and "change the rules" on the go. What is that pattern supposed to do? More, if I replaced `\b \b` with `\s+` I really mean it, it is better. Do not use a space at the start, use just `\b`. Why use `{0,0}`? Do you understand it won't match anything as if the whole group was missing from the pattern? Which of my two above patterns works as you need?

Comment: And another performance hint you should not reject: never write alternations that match at the same location. `(sa|sb|sd|sg|sj)` should be `s(a|b|d|g|j)`. The rest can also be enhanced, but you get the point.

Comment: I still do not understand if you want to match `I` and `can` in `I can ßtake that`. See https://regex101.com/r/d6YZYA/6

Comment: I spent some time with trying the tool on the link you sended (good tool, thanks). I tested only the `(?!not)` I am going to do some more tests with your next code.

Comment: Your code works: https://regex101.com/r/d6YZYA/2 ; note I have removed the link on the confusing example. You can send it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a [branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) to match an empty string if there is `not` as a whole word after a modal verb, or a notional verb otherwise:

```
\b(I|you|he|she|it|we|they|this|that|these|those)\s+(can|should|would|could|must|want to|have to|had to|might)\s+\K(?|(?=not\b)()|([^ß\W]\w{2,15})\b)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d6YZYA/2)

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(I|you|he|she|it|we|they|this|that|these|those)` - one of the pronouns in the group 1
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces (it is already acting as a word boundary on both sides of the adjacent groups)
- `(can|should|would|could|must|want to|have to|had to|might)` - one ofthe modal verbs
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `(?|(?=not\b)()|([^ß\W]\w{2,15})\b)` - the branch reset group matching either

  - `(?=not\b)()` - if there is `not` as whole word immediately to the right, capture an empty string into Group 3
  - `|` - or (here, else)
  - `([^ß\W]\w{2,15})\b` - match and capture into Group 3 any word char other than `ß` and then 2 to 15 word chars with a word boundary to follow.

Note that `(?m)` - `PCRE_MULTILINE` - is only necessary if you want your `^` and `$` outside of character classes match start and end of *lines* rather than the whole string. Since your pattern has no such anchors, `(?m)` is redundant.

Comment: Maybe, there is a big difference: `I` and `can` in `I can ßtake that` will not be matched with https://regex101.com/r/d6YZYA/8

Comment: There does not exist this text: `I can ßtake` The ß occure after `not` before the verb. It says that the verb is "negatively" used. There are not things like that. There is only simple text with single space between words. That's why I use space instead \s .