# How to exclude a group of alternatives from regex subpattern?

Tags: regex, delphi

This question is very similar to my previous question:
[How to exclude a word from regex subpattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52542946/how-to-exclude-a-word-from-regex-subpattern)

Though, it is not the same, because the previous question was about one word only, while this question is pointed to have more words (alternatives) which I want to exclude.

**First group:**
The list of words which I want to exclude from the match:
`(thy|your|her|his|its|our|their|mine|yours|hers|ours|theirs|my|a|an|the)`
That is a list of pronoun possessive and articles.

**Second group:**
The list of words that should match the second group:

`(bore|bade|bit|blew|chose|dove|drew|drove|drank|ate|fell|forbade|forgot|forgave|forsook|froze|got|gave|went|grew|hid|knew|lay|lit|mistook|overdid|overtook|overthrew|rode|rang|rose|saw|shook|shore|shrank|sang|sank|smote|spoke|stole|stank|strod|strove|swore|swam|took|threw|trod|woke|wore|wove|wrote)`

**Sample text**

```
1) And Ôhe spoke to him
2) and spoke to his sons
3) his host, spoke to
4) and took of every
5) and * took a garment
6) And * took * his son
7) merchants fetched a drove of horses
8) ÔI am a rose
9) blossom like a rose
10) But a † rose out
11) that * rose up
12) and a bit
13) and Ôthey bit the people
```

**Positive match expected:**

1) And Ôhe spoke to him
2) and spoke to his sons
3) his host, spoke to
4) and took of every
5) and * took a garment
6) And * took * his son
11) that * rose up
13) and Ôthey bit the people

**To be skipped:**

```
7) merchants fetched a drove of horses
8) ÔI am a rose
9) blossom like a rose
10) But a † rose out
12) and a bit
```

That means, any word which has a particle (a, an, the) should be skipped ... and I dont want to capture the following word, because it is not a verb. Also if there is the pronoun possessive like `yours` so it is not a verb, so this must not be captured.

My current pattern which I tried looks like this:

```
'(*UCP)\W\K(?|(?=(your|her|his|its|our|their|mine|yours|hers|ours|theirs|my|a|an|the)\b)()|(\w+)\b)\W\b(bore|bade|bit|blew|chose|dove|drew|drove|drank|ate|fell|forbade|forgot|forgave|forsook|froze|got|gave|went|grew|hid|knew|lay|lit|mistook|overdid|overtook|overthrew|rode|rang|rose|saw|shook|shore|shrank|sang|sank|smote|spoke|stole|stank|strod|strove|swore|swam|took|threw|trod|woke|wore|wove|wrote)\b(?=\W)'
```

Or I tried to changing `(\w+)` to `(\w+|\*)`

https://regex101.com/r/d6YZYA/10

Yet a note:

The star * represents noun. That's why I need capture the word `took` from 5) and 6).

```
5) and * took a garment
6) And * took * his son
```

Sign † is a gerundium, that is a none.

Current result is not correct. I see the articles and pronouns possesive to be captured, so the words which are not verbs are incorrectly identified.

Comment: You keep using word boundaries where they should not. In my previous suggestions I explained their redundancy where whitespaces are obligatory. Why use `(?=\s)` at the end? You already have a `\b` that does a good job - what is wrong with it? Try https://regex101.com/r/d6YZYA/11

Comment: Yet a note, sign † is a gerundium, that is a none.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew: Another attempt with not good result https://regex101.com/r/d6YZYA/14  `a dove` and `a bit` still captured (should be skipped).

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/d6YZYA/15.

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly. I added the cross sign (gerundium substitute) too https://regex101.com/r/d6YZYA/16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
(*UCP)(?<!\w)(?!(?:your?|hers?|his|its|ours?|theirs?|mine|my|an?|the)\b)(\w+|[*†]),?\s+(bore|bade|bit|blew|chose|dove|drew|drove|drank|ate|fell|forbade|forgot|forgave|forsook|froze|got|gave|went|grew|hid|knew|lay|lit|mistook|overdid|overtook|overthrew|rode|rang|rose|saw|shook|shore|shrank|san[gk]|smote|spoke|stole|stank|strove|swore|swam|took|threw|s?trod|wo[krv]e|wrote)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d6YZYA/17)

NOTE:

- The first `\b` is replaced with `(?<!\w)` unambiguous word boundary because `*` and the gerundium symbols are non-word chars, and `\b` before them requires a word char to be present immediately to the left of them
- There is a comma after `host` in Sentence 3, thus, I added an optional `,?` after the first capturing group
- The conditional does not work to exclude the words here, a restrictive negative lookahead forbids the first capturing group to match the list of words listed in the negative lookahead

**Pattern details**

- `(*UCP)` - all shorthand classes are now Unicode aware
- `(?<!\w)` - no word char immediately to the left of the current location is allowed
- `(?!(?:your?|hers?|his|its|ours?|theirs?|mine|my|an?|the)\b)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is one of the words listed (`his`, `her`, `hers`, etc.)
- `(\w+|[*†])` - Group 1: one or more word chars or `*` or `†`
- `,?\s+` - an optional `,` and then 1+ whitespaces
- `(bore|bade|bit|blew|chose|dove|drew|drove|drank|ate|fell|forbade|forgot|forgave|forsook|froze|got|gave|went|grew|hid|knew|lay|lit|mistook|overdid|overtook|overthrew|rode|rang|rose|saw|shook|shore|shrank|san[gk]|smote|spoke|stole|stank|strove|swore|swam|took|threw|s?trod|wo[krv]e|wrote)` - Group 2: any of the words (patterns) inside the group
- `\b` - a word boundary (all the words above end with a word char, so `\b` is enough).

Answer (score 1):

Now I have found great article, which explains how to use if else conditions.

https://regular-expressions.mobi/conditional.html?wlr=1

This explains using of the if condition in detailed way.

So basic syntax is:

```
(?(?=regex)then|else)
```

Syntax for using alternation is:

```
(?(?=condition)(then1|then2|then3)|(else1|else2|else3))
```

That's really useful stuff!